# How to convert flask app into google cloud functions

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to convert my flask app to google cloud functions. Functions are stateless and I am confused about how I should do this. I have simplified my app so if anyone could help me simply it to pure python so that I can deploy it as google cloud functions.

```
OAUTH = OAuth(APP)
MSGRAPH = OAUTH.remote_app(
    'microsoft', consumer_key=config.CLIENT_ID, consumer_secret=config.CLIENT_SECRET,
    request_token_params={'scope': config.SCOPES},
    base_url=config.RESOURCE + config.API_VERSION + '/',
    request_token_url=None, access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url=config.AUTHORITY_URL + config.TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
    authorize_url=config.AUTHORITY_URL + config.AUTH_ENDPOINT)



@APP.route('/login')
def login():
    """Prompt user to authenticate."""
    flask.session['state'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    return MSGRAPH.authorize(callback=config.REDIRECT_URI, state=flask.session['state'])

@APP.route('/login/authorized')
def authorized():
    """Handler for the application's Redirect Uri."""
    if str(flask.session['state']) != str(flask.request.args['state']):
        raise Exception('state returned to redirect URL does not match!')
    response = MSGRAPH.authorized_response()
    flask.session['access_token'] = response['access_token']
    return return "200"


@MSGRAPH.tokengetter
def get_token():
    """Called by flask_oauthlib.client to retrieve current access token."""
    return (flask.session.get('access_token'), '')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This app won't translate well into Cloud Functions: you're sharing session state between each route, and Cloud Functions are stateless.

Depending on how you're storing this state (i.e. if it's not just in-memory) you might be better off deploying your app to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/).

Comment: Is there no way to implement this using cloud functions?

Comment: What is your goal for using Cloud Functions? Cloud functions work best when each function is independent and does not depend on state from other functions.

Comment: My goal is to read emails using microsoft graph api and store them in azure database using google cloud functions.

Comment: Why do you need logins and sessions then?

Comment: To authenticate the user(Oauth)

Comment: This would be a better fit for Cloud Run: these functions cannot operate independently of each other. You already have a Flask app, so it should be straightforward to deploy it to Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy

Comment: @DustinIngram Since Cloud Run can scale up, a route can be served by another instance and state would be lost. Instead of using flask's session, would one not be better off passing on the token (or similar required session_id) in all requests ?

Comment: Yes, presumably you'd pass session IDs in the request and do some kind of server-side session storage in Redis or something similar to share state.